# Discrepancy in eigenvalues

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I need to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix and the parameters are such that there is a large difference (several orders of magnitude) between the entries. Theoretically, the matrix has only one zero eigenvalue.

For a particular choice of parameters, this matrix looks like:

```
M = {{0.0040344, 0.0492, 30.258}, {0.0492, 0.6, 369}, {30.258, 369, 226935}}
```

If I use three different alternatives to calculate the eigenvalues,

1. `Eigensystem[M]`
2. `Eigenvalues[M]`
3. `U = Eigenvectors[M];` and then `U.M.Transpose[U]`

I get different results due to numerical precision. Is there a way to deal with this issue? I read about `MatrixLog` but my matrices have a zero eigenvalue. Thanks.

Comment: `I get different results.` if you add `//Chop` at the end, you see they are all the same eigenvalues. `{226936., 0, 0}`  The differences are all rounding errors due to use of different linpack functions or different code path I assume. But the differences are insignificant since you see that `//Chop` removes them (otherwise it will not)

Comment: From help on Chop `Chop[expr]
replaces approximate real numbers in expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0.`  `uses a default tolerance of 10^-10`

Comment: Thanks, Nasser. Theoretically, this matrix should have only one zero eigenvalue so I’m not sure how to set the tolerance in this case.

Comment: Just do `Chop[Eigensystem[M], 10^(-15)]` and you will get ONE zero eigenvalue. But you'll need different tolerance for the other methods.  Are you sure there is only ONE zero eigenvalue? Since using exact input, it says there are two zero eigenvalues. Try `M = Rationalize[M]` then `Eigenvalues[M]` it gives `{283669505043/1250000, 0, 0}` So it looks like there are two zero eigenvalues, not one?

Comment: Let me double check, thanks!

Comment: According to the paper I’m following, there is only one zero eigenvalue. The actual expression for the matrix is ugly and I just put here some decimals for each entry. Could that be the reason? I can’t prove analytically that there is only one null eigenvalue, so I expected to do it numerically.

Comment: It is certainly possible that machine precision is insufficient to resolve your problem of verifying that the matrix only has one zero eigenvalue. Perhaps you should link to the paper that you mention.

Comment: "and I just put here some decimals for each entry". Please put precise matrix.